# How do I download an uber jar dependency to a specific local location/folder?

Tags: java, maven

Using shade I'm uploading an uberjar to a repo:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
          <shadedClassifierName>myjar</shadedClassifierName>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Then I have another app that needs to access that jar. I was planning on just having a pom in the other apps repository and have deploy scripts calling mvn install or whatever to download the uber jar locally. I'm not sure how to just download the uber jar.

This POM creates a `blahblah-1.jar` in the target folder when I run `mvn install`. What I want is to have it pull down the uber jar into a specific directory. How can I do this in a pom config? I don't want to have to pass specific params to `mvn`; I want the config to be in the pom so I can just execute something like `mvn install` and it pulls down the uber jar dependency into the right directory. I want to use a pom for all settings because this will mean my CI/CD server just needs to call the same command for other apps like this and the settings will be in pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>derps</groupId>
  <artifactId>blahblah</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>

  <!-- Retrieve artifacts from internal repo -->
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>myrepo</id>
      <name>my repo</name>
      <url>https://myrepo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <classifier>myjar</classifier>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use maven dependency plugin to copy dependency in particular folder:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html

Comment: That works for me but i cant change the name of the jar. I opened another issue about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58173663/destfilename-is-ignored-by-mvn-install-dependencycopy-dependencies