# destFileName is ignored by mvn install dependency:copy-dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to change the local folder and name of a jar when copying down dependencies with this command `mvn install dependency:copy-dependencies`

destFileName seems to be ignored by maven. Although outputDirectory does correctly put it in that directory the jar name is not changed- it is the same name as it is in the repo. I want to completely change the name of the jar when it is copied down

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <!-- required by not used -->
  <groupId>aaaa</groupId>
  <artifactId>aaaaa</artifactId>
  <version>5</version>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>my-repo</id>
      <name>repo</name>
      <url>https://my-repo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <!-- require uber-jar -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <classifier>uber-jar</classifier>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>Jars</outputDirectory>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
              <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
              <classifier>uber-jar</classifier>
              <overWrite>true</overWrite>


              <!-- THIS IS IGNORED -->
              <destFileName>zzzzzz.jar</destFileName>


            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
          <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
          <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Does Maven output any error?

Comment: nope it does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I may have the answer copy-dependencies seems to not have destFileName

[copy-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html)

but the goal copy has it

[copy](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html)

I had a similar problem of your you could try to use the `<stripVersion>` options in the copy-dependencies

Hope it helps

Comment: hmm guess im confused. what is the diff between copy and copy-dependencies and when would you use one over the other. did a quick test and just switching from copy-dependencies to copy works, but is there any significant differences I should know about? if they are interchangeable then why is there two versions of the same goal?